# Xcode5 won't allow Frame Debugger / Analyze button is greyed out

Tags: opengl-es, xcode5

Xcode 4.2+ and Xcode 5 have a very powerful debugger for OpenGL ES. Until recently, the debugger itself would crash often (it didn't work reliably for me until Xcode5.0), but it sometimes disables itself and refuses to run at all.

This being an Apple application, they don't bother with error messages, they simply refuse to let you press the Analyze button:

[image: Analyze disabled]

I can't find any reference in Apple's docs to a situation that would "disable" the analysis. I know that it *can* work on this machine, because it worked fine on a different device.

Device that works:

- iPad3, running iOS 6.x

Device that Xcode5 refuses to work with:

- iPad Mini, running iOS 7.x

...I've tried updating to latest 7.x - no change. Xcode just refuses to work properly. All other debugging works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect answer, but I've noticed something that might explain it...

When you pause the debugger, this triggers the button to grey-out. So, if you needed to analyse the frame at a particular point in your app ... you can't.

It sucks, and I have no idea how you're supposed to debug something without using the debugger, but ... it might be why I was getting disabled button!